# Flutter - How to generate very short unique id?

Tags: flutter

I want to generate very short unique iD in my apps for sharing stuff between users and i don't want theses codes to be too long or too complicated.

I found shortid 0.1.1 (https://pub.dev/packages/shortid) but it seems to be deprecate and not maintained.

Also found shortuuid that can do the trick but a bit long (https://pub.dev/packages/shortuuid) i will take this option if no one can find a better one.

Looking for something like this

```
print(shortid.generate());
// PPBqWA9
```

EDIT :
This is what i need : https://pub.dev/packages/nanoid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefer UUID(https://pub.dev/packages/uuid)

**Dependency:**

```
dependencies:
  uuid: 2.2.2
```

**Code:**

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

var uuid = Uuid();
// Generate a v1 (time-based) id
print(uuid.v1()); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a'

// Generate a v4 (random) id
print(uuid.v4()); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a smaller return value ? like 10 char maximum ? By the way tanks for your answer.

Comment: Ideally, you should use the entire UUID as that is more accurate and unique, but in case you want a small String you can use  String uuid = '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a';
  print(uuid.substring(0, 13));

Comment: I will accept your answer but i will make my own string generator based on data i already have. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: finaly found : https://pub.dev/packages/nanoid that fit what i need

Comment: @JasonSimard: I still recommend to use UUID, as I personally used so many times, that was never wrong. just keep this around to use in future.

Comment: Do NOT use a substring of the UUID as a "shorter" unique string. Only the full string is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @Abion47: Similar suggestion, I gave.

Comment: If you want shorter ones, I would take a look to the sluuid Dart package: https://pub.dev/packages/slugid, but I did not try it, so no idea about how well it works :)

Answer (score 0):

try this to use the remainder of DateTime when divided by any whole number,

DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.remainder(100000).toString();

Comment: This wont be unique

Answer (score 0):

To generate a unique ID you can use this code

```dart
import 'package:id_gen/id_gen.dart';

final gen = UuidV4Gen();

final uuid = gen.next;
final uuidInt = gen.next.hash();                    // 2^64 native
final uuidIntShort = gen.next.hash() & 0xFFFFFFFF;  // 2^32
final uuidIntShortest = gen.next.hash() & 0xFFFF;   // 2^16
```

from the lightweight and well-tested Dart package https://pub.dev/packages/id_gen